# Is event parameter compulsory in EventListener.handleEvent()?

Tags: javascript, dom

In mozilla doc the `handleEvent` method is declared as

```
eventListener.handleEvent(event);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent

and `addEventListener` as

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax

with `listener` being `handleEvent` or object containing such method, but on the exact same page there's an example:

```
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyText() {
  ...
}

// add event listener to table
var el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

where `modifyText` takes no parameters, which contradicts with `handleEvent` syntax, though everything works, where am I missing?

Comment: You only need it if you're going to use it, but also there's no problem with not using it when it's supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as many arguments as you want to a function, no matter how many parameters it has. Those additional arguments then get lost (but if they aren't used that doesn't matter).

```
 function handler(a) {
  //...
 }

 handler(); // a = undefined
 handler(1); // a = 1
 handler(1, 2); // a = 1, ? = 2
```

Therefore if you don't need to access the event in the handler, you can just omit the parameter.

*PS: Those "lost arguments" can still be accessed using the `arguments` keyword ... but please, never ever use this*

Comment: much appreciated!